# Why am I getting no output from JavaScript with this code?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone see if there is an obvious problem with my code below. It's a very straight forward HTML page with JavaScript to add two inputted numbers or o multiply them. At the moment I'm getting no output. Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" name="myform">
Please enter your Numbers:<br/>
   Number 1: <input type=text id="number1" name="num1"/><br/>
   Number 2:<input type=text id="number2" name="num2"/><br/><br/>
   <input type=button name="add" id="add" value="Add" onclick="addNumbers()"/>
   <input type=button name="add" id="multiply" value="Multiply" onclick="multNumbers()"/><br/>

   <table name="mytable" id="t">
   </table>
   </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var num1=document.getElementById('number1').value;
    var num2=document.getElementById('number2').value;
    var result="";

    addNumbers(){
    result=num1+num2;
    document.getElementById('t').innerHTML=result;
    }

    multNumbers(){
    result=num1*num2;
    document.getElementById('t').innerHTML=result;
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It really helps if you look at the errors in your JavaScript console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the function as **Oriol** said, and also you need to make the input value integer like

```
var num1= +(document.getElementById('number1').value);
```

Or

```
var num1= parseInt(document.getElementById('number1').value, 10);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vzd9M/)

Comment: `+document.getElementById('number1').value` works without parentheses, and it's much faster than `parseInt`

Comment: yeah for readibility I put the `()` parenthesis sign.

Answer (score 4):

Your function declarations are missing the `function` keyword.
And in your functions you need to retrieve the input values when they are called.

```
function addNumbers() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById('number1').value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById('number2').value;

  var result = num1 + num2;

  // since your target is a table:
  var table = document.getElementById('t');
  // you need to create a row
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  // and in the row a cell
  var td = row.insertCell(-1);
  td.textContent = result;
}
```

EDIT

```
 var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('number1').value, 10);
 var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('number2').value, 10);
```

Or for decimals:

```
 var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('number1').value);
 var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('number2').value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You must declare functions using `function`:

```
function addNumbers(){ /* ... */ }          // Function Statement
```

or

```
var addNumbers = function(){ /* ... */ };   // Function Expression
```

instead of

```
addNumbers(){ /* ... */ }
```